# AWS: Cannot delete client certificate. Certificate ID 'XXXXX', is referenced in stage prod

Tags: amazon-web-services, certificate

I have created an API Gateway and a lambda on AWS. I use them for an application. I'm having issues with certification error on the lambda call. So I created a certificate and I linked it to my api gateway.
AWS say me that I'm gonna pay (too much) so I tried to remove the certificate, then this error happened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove the association of ACM certificate from API Gateway first.

Guide:
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/acm-certificate-resources/